# Mocking an object methods response using Pytest

Tags: flask, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to test the following function:

```
def geocode_postcode(postcode: str) -> tuple:
    """
    Turn the postcode into a longitude and latitude point

    Inputs
        postocde: postocde for the UK

    Outputs
        point: longitude and latitude as a tuple (longitude, latitude) else None
    """
    try:

        if not postcode or not isinstance(postcode, str):
            raise ValueError("Invalid postcode format")
        
        with Bing(api_key=CONFIG.BING_API_KEY) as geolocator:
            point_location = geolocator.geocode(
                query={"postalCode":postcode,
                        "countryRegion":"UK"},
                exactly_one=True
            )

        if point_location:
            point = (point_location.longitude, point_location.latitude)
        else:
            point = None

        return point
    
    except (GeocoderTimedOut, GeocoderServiceError) as e:
        print(f"Error geocoding postcode {postcode}: {e}")
        return None
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

Without having to call the Bing API to geocode. I basically want to ensure that it runs properly as expected. At the moment I am using:

```
from petrol_locations.helpers import geocode_postcode
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
import pytest

class StubResponse():
    def __init__(self, longitude, latitude):
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude

@patch("petrol_locations.helpers.Bing")
def test_geocode_postcode_success(mock_geocode):
    mock_response = StubResponse(0,0)
    mock_geocode.return_value.geocode.return_value = mock_response
    response = geocode_postcode("SW1A 2AA")
    print(response)
    assert response == (0, 0)
```

But I get the error:

```
========================================================================================================= FAILURES ==========================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_geocode_postcode_success _______________________________________________________________________________________________

mock_geocode = <MagicMock name='Bing' id='139699539770480'>

    @patch("petrol_locations.helpers.Bing")
    def test_geocode_postcode_success(mock_geocode):
        mock_response = StubResponse(0,0)
        mock_geocode.return_value.geocode.return_value = mock_response
        response = geocode_postcode("SW1A 2AA")
        print(response)
>       assert response == (0, 0)
E       AssertionError: assert (<MagicMock n...99539985984'>) == (0, 0)
E         At index 0 diff: <MagicMock name='Bing().__enter__().geocode().longitude' id='139699539973984'> != 0
E         Use -v to get more diff

tests/test_helpers.py:34: AssertionError
```

And the response object looks like:

```
(<MagicMock name='Bing().__enter__().geocode().longitude' id='139699539973984'>, <MagicMock name='Bing().__enter__().geocode().latitude' id='139699539985984'>)
```

Rather than (0,0). Any advice or help here would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error came from the way in which the `geocode_postcode` function was implemented using the `with` keyword. To get around this it could be done such that I mocked the geocode function rather than `Bing`:

```
class StubResponse:
    def __init__(self, longitude, latitude):
        self._longitude = longitude
        self._latitude = latitude

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        return self._longitude
    
    @property
    def latitude(self):
        return self._latitude

def test_postcode_Function(mocker):
    mocker.patch("petrol_locations.helpers.Bing.geocode", return_value=StubResponse(0, 0))
    response = geocode_postcode("SWA1 1AY")
    assert response == (0, 0)
```

Or refactoring the function to remove the `with` statement:

```
def geocode_postcode(postcode: str) -> tuple:
    """
    Turn the postcode into a longitude and latitude point

    Inputs
        postocde: postocde for the UK

    Outputs
        point: longitude and latitude as a tuple (longitude, latitude) else None
    """
    try:

        if not postcode or not isinstance(postcode, str):
            raise ValueError("Invalid postcode format")
        
        # with Bing(api_key=CONFIG.BING_API_KEY) as geolocator:
        #     point_location = geolocator.geocode(
        #         query={"postalCode":postcode,
        #                 "countryRegion":"UK"},
        #         exactly_one=True
        #     )
        geolocator = Bing(api_key=CONFIG.BING_API_KEY)

        point_location = geolocator.geocode(
                query={"postalCode":postcode,
                        "countryRegion":"UK"},
                exactly_one=True
        )

        if point_location:
            point = (point_location.longitude, point_location.latitude)
        else:
            point = None

        return point
    
    except (GeocoderTimedOut, GeocoderServiceError) as e:
        print(f"Error geocoding postcode {postcode}: {e}")
        return None
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

Which could then be tested:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_geolocator():
    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.geocode.return_value = StubResponse(0, 0)
    with patch("petrol_locations.helpers.Bing", return_value=mock):
        yield mock

def test_geocode_postcode_success(mocked_geolocator):
    postcode = 'SW1A 2AA'
    result = geocode_postcode(postcode)
    assert result == (0, 0)
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.assert_called_once_with(query={'postalCode': postcode, 'countryRegion': 'UK'}, exactly_one=True)

def test_geocode_postcode_invalid_postcode(mocked_geolocator):
    postcode = ''
    result = geocode_postcode(postcode)
    assert result is None
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.assert_not_called()

def test_geocode_postcode_geocode_timeout(mocked_geolocator):
    postcode = 'SW1A 2AA'
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.side_effect = GeocoderTimedOut()
    result = geocode_postcode(postcode)
    assert result is None
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.assert_called_once_with(query={'postalCode': postcode, 'countryRegion': 'UK'}, exactly_one=True)


def test_geocode_postcode_geocode_service_error(mocked_geolocator):
    postcode = 'SW1A 2AA'
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.side_effect = GeocoderServiceError()
    result = geocode_postcode(postcode)
    assert result is None
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.assert_called_once_with(query={'postalCode': postcode, 'countryRegion': 'UK'}, exactly_one=True)

def test_geocode_postcode_invalid_postcode_format(mocked_geolocator):
    postcode = 123
    result = geocode_postcode(postcode)
    assert result is None
    mocked_geolocator.geocode.assert_not_called()
```

Because I no longer need to "**enter**()" the function as I had to with the `with` statement. I am still not sure why this is the case or how I could resolve it otherwise but yeah.